# Cross Validation--Use testing set or validation set to predict?

Tags: validation, machine-learning

I have a question about cross validation.

In Machine learning, we know there're training, validation, test set.
And test set is final run to see how the final model/classifier performed.

But in the process of cross validation:
we are splitting data into training set and testing set(most tutorial used this term), so I'm confused. Do we need to split the whole data into 3 parts: training, validation, test? Since in cross validation we just keep talking about relationship with 2 set: training and the other.

Could someone help clarify?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is generally an either-or choice.  The process of cross-validation is, by design, another way to validate the model.  You don't need a separate validation set -- the interactions of the various train-test partitions replace the need for a validation set.

Think about the name, *cross*-validation ... :-)

Comment: oh... So they are just 2 ways to avoid overfitting: one the cross validation; another is separate to 3 sets(train, test, validation)? Is that correct?

Comment: In terms of splitting the data, it can be split as Train Validation and Test, or Train Test and use CV, or even both together.
 In the end the the train set is used to create the best weights for the model, the validation is used to choose the best model, and the test shows how your final model. 

There are many ways to avoid overfitting: feature reduction, dropout, batch norm, regularization.

Answer (score 9):

Yep ,it's a little confusing as some material uses CV/test interchangeably and some material does not use ,but i'll try to make it easy to understand by giving the comprehension of why it's needed:

You need the train set to do exactly that, train, but then also you need a way to ensure that your algorithm isn't memorizing the train set(that it's not overfitting) and how well its doing, so that makes the need of the test set so you can give it data it has never seen and you can measure the performance.

But.... ML its all about experimentation, you will  train, evaluate, tweak some knob(hyperparameters or architectures), train again, evaluate again over and over, and then you will select the best experiment results, you deploy your system and in production it gets data it's never seen and it doesn't perform that well ,what happened?  You used your test data to fit parameters and make decisions , so you overfitted to this test data but you dont know how it does to data never seen.

Cross validation solves this, you have your train data to learn parameters, and test data to evaluate how it does on unseen data, but still need a way to experiment the best hyper parameters and architectures: you take a sample of your training data and call it cross validation set, and hide your test data , you will  NEVER use it until the end.

Now use your train data to learn parameters, and experiment with hyper parameters and architectures, but you will evaluate each experiment on the cross validation data instead of test data(you can see it as using CV data as a way to learn the hyperparameters) , after you experimented a lot, and selected your best performing option(on CV),  you now use your test data to evaluate how it performs on data it has never seen before deploying it to production.

Comment: Speaking of choose the best performance model, could you advise in machine learning how can we tell which models are better, just error?

Comment: Not just error, it depends on the type of problem(regression,classification, etc) , there's distinct performance metrics ,and for every specific problem , some metric can be adequate ,and some other don't  .The typical example: if you develop a spam classification ML system, what's worst? to get an undesired email on your inbox, or to lose important mail that was misclassified as Spam but wasn't ? Obviously ,its worst to lose an important mail, so you use the adequate metric

Comment: Or if you develop a illness  detection system, you can: diagnose the a healthy patient as ill, that would make him go to additional exams, but if you diagnose an ill patient as healthy, we wont get treatment, so it's better to have false positives than false negatives. Check metrics package of sklearn:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#sklearn-metrics-metrics

Comment: The second  option, deploy the model fitted on training data only, but there's a technique called k-fold cross validation in which you use all your data as both training and validation data